# Lightning, display object fields on a different tab

Tags: lightning, tab, page-layout

We are currently Experimenting with customizations in Salesforce and are trying to achieve the following:

We have added several custom fields to the Account object and want these and other fields to be displayed (and edited) in a different tab. I know it is possible to create different layouts for an object, but have not been able to figure out how to assign these different layouts on different tabs. I can only assign a layout to a profile.

If it has to be done with code, would it be possible to render a layout with a lightning component?

[image: Move fields to other tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight answer would be - you cannot do this,

But there are workarounds, even with a customization solution.

This  is a new solution but it works great:

1. Go to your object's setup page
2. Go to the `Buttons, Links, and Actions` section
3. Click `New Action`
4. on 'Action Type' select `Update a Record`
5. enter all other data as you want and click `save`:

[image]

6. The next page is a layout page - fill all the fields that you want:

[image]

7. click `save` - now you have created the layout of the update action.
8. You can now select `Predefined Field Values` as you like...
9. now you need to add this layout to your app builder:
10. Go back to your object setup page and open and edit your `Lightning Record Page`
11. Add a tab
12. Add to your tab the `Related Record` standard lightning component
13. enter header
14. in the 'Lookup field' enter `Use this Object`
15. In the 'Update Action' select the layout you have created:

[image]

16. Save the record page (and activate it if you haven't done it untill now)

That's it

Enjoy!!!

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot for the effort in answering this question, very clear and well written! :-)

Comment: This is a new feature so I want a good manual to do that...

Comment: One thing I found out - this method does not display formula fields!!!

Comment: Update: on the new Winter 18 release read only fields like formulas are displayed on the layout of actions